# Mongoose не вызывает createIndex

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Не понимаю почему mongoose не вызывает createIndex НА новой модели. В коллекции в mongo shell индексы, указанные в схеме модели, не отображаются (потому что не создаются); есть лишь только один индекс на поле _id.

Удалял коллекцию в moongo shell не один раз и пытался проверить снова, но всё напрасно. Также пытался убрать useCreateIndex в конфиге mongoose, но мне даже deprecation warning не выдаёт, типа ensureIndex is deprecated, use createIndex instead.

В mongo shell индекс спокойно создаётся через createIndex, но это не дело. Толку тогда от схемы мангуста..

Options при подключении к мангусту:

```
{
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "useFindAndModify": false,
    "useCreateIndex": true,
    "useUnifiedTopology": true
}
```

Файл модели (mongoose.connect не добавлен в пример):

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const schema = new Schema({
    telegramId: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true }
});
    
module.exports = model('User', schema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я также объявлял методы для этой модели, один из которых имел имя **init**, и по сути заменял системный метод **init** mongoose, что привело к данной ошибке.